# Jasmine : spy on a function called X times, and get the n-th call

Tags: javascript, jasmine, expectations

I can't seem to find a solution online.

Here is a sample of code so you get the issue :

```js
// Spy on the wanted function
spyOn(object, 'myFunction');

// Call it 3 times with different parameters
object.myFunction('');
object.myFunction('', 0);
object.myFunction('', 0, true);

// Now all of these expects work
expect(object.myFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
expect(object.myFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith('', 0);
expect(object.myFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith('');
expect(object.myFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith('', 0, true);
```

I would like to test if every call was correctly made. Is there a way to say something like this ?

```
expect(object.myFunction).nthCall(2).toHaveBeenCalledWith('', 0, true);
```

???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's `calls` property, you can use like:
`expect(object.myFunction.calls.argsFor(2)).toEqual(['', 0, true])`

Comment: I don't have access to the `calls` property, maybe `call` ?

Comment: @trichetriche sorry, I've made a mistake. now edited

Comment: @trichetriche that's wired, you should: https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Other_tracking_properties are you sure, that `object.myFunction` is a spy?

Comment: Oh wait, I forgot to mention I use Typescript, could it be that my definitions aren't up-to-date ? (the project is about 1 month old)

Comment: And object.myFunction isn't a spy, it's a function that I spy on. I don't know if this is what you meant ?

Comment: It's a spy, in terms of jasmine. Well... typescript may be an issue, but `calls` is older than one month

Comment: Oh wait : In my IDE, the function was still typed as a class. I used `(object.myFunction as jasmine.Spy)`, and it gave me calls ! thank you for your help :)